# Java: Connection Timedout and Socket Timedout

Tags: java, sockets, connection, timeout

I'm in the process of writing two Junit testcases for testing the timemouts

```
@Test
    public void connectionTimeoutTest()
    {
        String myurl = "http://serverip:serverport/context";
        URL url = new URL(myurl);
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();

        //how to check connectionTimeout but not socket time out

        //what I think
        //is it good enough to check with a server ip that does not exist ?
    }

    @Test
    public void socketTimeoutTest()
    {
        String myurl = "http://localhost:serverport/context";
        URL url = new URL(myurl);
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();

        //how to check successful connection and timesout at socket (or port)

        //what I think
        //IP should exist (so it is localhost) but should not be listening on the port
    }
```

I'm confused here because I'm not sure if my approach is right. What are the exceptions in each case ? Also, is it possible to differentiate based on Exceptions ?

Are there any other time outs that I have missed ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `URLConnection.setConnectTimeout()` before opening any streams or getting the response code. It will throw a `ConnectException` with the text 'connection timed out' if a connect timeout happens.

Note that, contrary to the Javadoc, the default connect timeout is about a minute (platform-dependent), not infinity, and that you can decrease the default connection timeout this way, but not increase it.

For a read timeout, which I assume is what you mean by 'socket timeout', you have to call `URLConnection.setReadTimeout()`. If it fires, you will get a `SocketTimeoutException`. In this case zero does mean infinity as per the Javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too clear on your unit test requirements. If you are to test the connection (and socket read) timeout values of the server, the approach mentioned above will only allow you to validate a certain "maximum" threshold value. But you still won't be able to confirm TCP server side timeout settings. The TCP server's connection (and read) timeouts depend upon factors such as platform (OS) and TCP stack implementation.

Again, the timeout setting via `setConnectTimeout` or `setReadTimeout()` are only on the client socket, when communicating with the resource referenced by this URLConnection.

Answer (score -1):

In the first test case, I think it will get java.net.UnknownHostException, because of non-exist ip address.

If you wanna cause a socket connect timeout exception (exactly get messages like "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out") , just use URLConnection.setConnectTimeout(10), set the parameter as smaller as possible ,but positive;

The same in the second test case, you can use URLConnection.setReadTimeout(10) to cause a read timeout exception ("java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out").

Comment: You can't get 'java,net SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out'. Connect timeouts are reported as ConnectExceptions, not as SocketTimeoutExceptions.

Comment: public static void testConnectTimeout(){
  final String url = "http://stackoverflow.com/";
  try {
   HttpURLConnection connect = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();
   connect.setRequestMethod("GET");
   connect.setConnectTimeout(10);
   connect.connect();
  } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }           Code segment, just try it...